# capture data from different cameras

Tags: python, scripting, game-engine, eevee-render-engine, opengl

I need this for my video game that I want to start on in Blender Game Engine.
I have not figured out how to use multiple cameras and make them give data out without them being active cams or without me logging inside of them.

So basicly what I want is cameras that are on the scene to record data and then send that data live to np arrays. The camera gets data feed and this feed results are passed to array. I want this because I want game characters to have camera on their heads.

Bpy.Render.Render does this, I can do this with bpy, but I have to save to file first and if I use viewer node to grab results that option is not there for me when I start the game in stand alone mode.

With Dynamic VideoTexture from bge.texture class, I managed to grab an image live from a camera   and send it to array and it works I get live data inside the array  without saving to file, but for the VideoTexture-bge.texture class I  have to be inside the camera for camera to record anything.

The first camera is indeed non active camera, it records data and then this data has to be projected on an object like a plane where you have a second camera to look at the wall plane and get image from there from what first camera sees, this is how render to texture works with bge.texture class. Also worth mentioning you cannot send data to arrray or save file if you don't set texture on that object, and you have to look at the object the texture is set on to record, otherwise it does not record data in array. So sending data to array with non active camera directly it is not possible to send data directly to array with bge.texture class with renderimage source. You have to capture it with a second camera where the texture sets.    I tried to use non active camera and feed the array but i get no results. Camera has to record and project data on another object where there is another camera mounted in font of the object to capture the projected texture on the wall, problem you are not inside the cam to see it, it does not record it

So I use `bge.texture.ImageRender(scene, camera)` for this but I cannot get any data if I'm out of the viewport.  I can do that with bpy.render.render grabbing an image from any camera sitting somewhere undisturbed that is non active but I have to save file to disk and then load back.

So bge.texture class let's me run things live and I get live results from this but I have to be in viewport from any cam I want to grab data from and send to array.
Here  is the texture class:
https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_76_0/bge.texture.html

With Bpy.Render.Render, I can get data from any cam sitting there that is non active but I have to save to file first and then load the image picture back from file, and that will load it into the buffer then I can insert it inside the array, this is resource consuming it does not work, it drags the frame rate down, saving frame by frame.

My render to texture code from bge.texture class.

```
import bge
import bpy
import sys

controller = bge.logic.getCurrentController()
own = controller.owner

## get current scene
scene = bge.logic.getCurrentScene()  



# check to see variable RenderToTexture has been created
if "RenderToTexture" in own:
    
 # update the texture
 own["RenderToTexture"].refresh(True)

# if variable RenderToTexture hasn't been created
else:
  
 # import VideoTexture module
 import VideoTexture
    
 # get a list of objects in the scene
 ownList = scene.objects
    
 cameraName = own['cam']

 cam = scene.cameras[cameraName]
 print(cameraName)

 # get the texture material ID
 matID = VideoTexture.materialID(own, "MA" + own['material'])

 # set the texture 
 renderToTexture = VideoTexture.Texture(own, matID)
 
 # Source that replaces the texture on the plane with the dynamic one
 renderToTexture.source = VideoTexture.ImageRender(scene,cam)

 renderToTexture.source.capsize = [30, 30]
 own["RenderToTexture"] = renderToTexture

 #Insert source into array
 arr = np.array(renderToTexture.source)
```

Works as long as I am there viewing the plane that I made as a vertical wall with the dynamic texture rendered on it. If I get out of viewport mode it no longer records the image.

I won't bother with Bpy.render.render since there is no way to call results after render, and data has to be loaded back from file.

Comment: I would recommend considering another game engine if you are only starting with your game and have this option. Video game technologies evolve rapidly, so it might make sense to choose a platform that is maintained and updated.

Comment: I'm considering it, not before I try all options, If it's not possible then I will switch. BGE is maintained, they give updates every 5 days with a new release build. https://upbge.org

Comment: Oh, OK, I thought you meant game engine in 2.79. I thought that's what we call Blender Game Engine, and UPBGE is now a separate thing. Did not seem like much was going on when I checked their website, I thought it's not so active.

Comment: It's a copy of the latest blender + game engine with evee. It's blender + game engine inside of it like good old times. Alpha 3 has updates weekly